# Animate SVG React Native

Tags: svg, react-native

I am trying to modify the height of a rectangle in svg. First of all my svg is correctly displayed before i use the Animated api. Then i try to bind a height variable to the SVG as So :

```
render() {
let AnimatedRectangle = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Rect);
let {height} = this.state
return (
  <View style={styles.wrapper}>
    <Svg height="100" width="100" x="0" y="0" fill="#333">
      <AnimatedRectangle
        x="0"
        y="0"
        width="4"
        height={height}
        fill="#333"
      />
      <Rect x="10" y="0" width="4" height="7" fill="#333" />
      <Rect x="20" y="0" width="4" height="7" fill="#333" />
    </Svg>
  </View>
);}
```

Here is my state and componentDidMount method :

```
state = {
  height: new Animated.Value(5)
};



 componentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(
      // Animate value over time
      this.state.height, // The value to drive
      {
        toValue: 30 // Animate to final value of 1
      }
    ).start(); // Start the animation
  }
```

This is not working even though my Animation is working. Indeed, if i bind the height to a simple Animated.View, the height is correctly modified.

Here is the error i am getting :

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but how about `height={\`${height}\`}`

Comment: @anhtu no unfortunetly.